# Any way to use function results for a countif conditional in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

For example I have a list of dates in A2 through A31 (1st April to 30th April) and want to count the number of weekdays.

In B2 to B31 I could use `=WEEKDAY(A2,2)<6` to give true or false. Then separately  count the trues.

Is there anyway to do it all in 1 cell with something similar to `=COUNTIF(A2:A31,WEEKDAY(A2,2)<6)`?

Comment: and another: https://superuser.com/questions/866590/excel-how-to-count-cells-whose-date-values-represent-a-day-between-monday-and

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this in inappropriate but in the answers of a "similar question" I found this unaccepted answer that is solving a different problem but also solved mine.

I don't think it's an obvious link between this question and what he was answering so I posted the question anyway and here is the answer that solved it for me.

[SeanC's answer](https://superuser.com/a/647133/893333)

You can give `WEEKDAY()` an array which isn't documented on Microsoft's website.

So the following worked for me. `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(WEEKDAY(A2:A31,2)<6))`

Changed `--` to `1*` thanks to [Bandersnatch](https://superuser.com/users/740226/bandersnatch)

Comment: Beat me by 14 seconds. :-) I like to use 1* instead of the double negation:  `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(WEEKDAY(A1:A30,2)<6))`.  I just think it looks cleaner.